# returning a structure in a function using typedef struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct

im trying to return a struct into main using the function addMovie that i have made please ignore the rest of the code this would only be applicable to case "a" of main. and when i apply to main does it have to be in a separate struct? how else would i be able to export it to main ? it needs to be saved to an array of stucture out of 100 which is defined at the top. the line return new; is giving me error

````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define CONST 100
void sortMovies(struct movies[]);
void changeMovie(struct movie[]);
int findMovie(struct movies[], int nOfMovies, struct movies[].UPC);
struct movies newMovie();
typedef struct {
    char title[30];
    char UPC[12];
    int qnty;
    double price;
}movies;

int main()
{
    int nOfMovies = 0, findR, stop = 0;
    char decider;
    while (stop != 1)
    {
        movies main[CONST];
        movies tempMovie;
        printf("(A)dd a new movie\n(C)hange a Movie's Information \n(D)elete a Movie \n(L)ist All Movies\n(Q)uit");
        scanf(" %c", &decider);

        switch (decider)
        {
        case 'a':
        case 'A':
            tempMovie = newMovie();
            nOfMovies = findMovie(movies[], nOfMovies, movies[].UPC);
            nOfMovies++;
            break;
        case 'c':
        case 'C':
            printf("enter movie upc:");
            scanf("%c", movies.UPC);
            findR = findMovie(movies, nOfMovies, movie.UPC);
            break;
        case 'd':
        case 'D':
            findR = findMovie(movie, nOfMovies, movie.UPC);
            if (findR != -1)
            {
                printf("are you sure?");
        case 'y':
        case 'Y':

            break;
        default:
            printf("An invalid option was selected!");

            }
            break;
        case 'l':
        case 'L':
            sortMovies(movie);
            break;
        case 'q':
        case 'Q':
            return 0;
            break;
        default:
            printf("An invalid option was selected!");
        }
    }


}
struct movies newMovie() {
    movies new;

    printf("enter movie upc:");
    scanf("%c", new.UPC);
    printf("enter movie title:");
    scanf("%c", new.title);
    printf("enter movie qauntity:");
    scanf("%d", new.qnty);
    if (new.qnty <= 0)
    {
        printf("quanitity must be greater than 0");
        printf("enter movie qauntity:");
        scanf("%d", new.qnty);
    }

    printf("enter movie price:");
    scanf("%lf", new.price);
    if (new.price <= 0)
    {
        printf("price must be greater than 0");
        printf("enter movie price:");
        scanf("%lf", new.price);
    }
    return new;
}```
````

Comment: You have `tempMovie = newMovie();`, but then never do anything with `tempMovie`? You have the data there, either store it in an array of struct, or do something with it like `main[nOfMovies++] = tempMovie;` (you cannot use any user-input function correctly unless you ***check the return*** -- otherwise you have no clue whether it succeeded or failed or the user generated an `EOF`)

Comment: So many issues with the code. `movies` is user defined data type. You need to declare a variable of that type and use it. But you have used the data type all over the code.
`findMovie(movies, nOfMovies, movie.UPC);`
`scanf("%c", movies.UPC);`

Comment: my main focus currently is why i cant return new in the function

Comment: You CAN return `new` (though since `new` is a keyword in C++ you may want to choose another name). `struct movies newMovie()` returns type `struct movies` (which is fine, a function can always return its *type*). You assign `tempMovie = newMovie();` capturing the return in `tempMovie` -- also fine. But then, inexplicably, you do nothing else with `tempMovie` -- the data is there -- it's just never used.

Comment: OOOH -- sorry, you need to define what `struct movies` is -- a `typedef` alone won't do. Either you need to change your function type to `movies newMovie()` or change your struct definition to `typedef struct movies { ... } movies;` Right now `struct movies` isn't declared or defined.

Comment: thanks that makes sense

Comment: this: `typedef struct {
    char title[30];
    char UPC[12];
    int qnty;
    double price;
}movies;` should be before the prototypes for the functions.  Since this is a typedef, the only word needed is `movies`  the `struct movies` is an error

Comment: regarding this kind of code: `case 'a':
        case 'A':`  Much better to include `ctype.h` then `switch(  toupper( decider ) )` and then only check for upper case values.

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%c", movies.UPC);`  a `UPC` is a whole string of characters. so the 'input format conversion' specifier `%c` will not do it.  Suggest:  `if( scanf("%11s", movies.UPC) != 1 ) { handle error and exit }`  Note: only a length of 11 because `%s` always appends a NUL byte to the input.  Similar considerations exist for: `scanf("%c", new.title);`